# FlexSlider fail slideshow

Tags: 7, javascript

I installed [FlexSlider](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider) as suggested on the module's in `Drupal7`. I try to put a slideshow on my home page with no luck. I tried to create the `FlexSlider Example` content but it does not create a slideshow, but only lists the images.

The FlexSlider libs are version 2.4.

The website is here: http://projects.busoniu.net/

the images are uploaded in the **FLEXSLIDER EXAMPLE SLIDESHOW** and I didn't upload any of it in the **FLEXSLIDER EXAMPLE IMAGE**.

I get an error when I try to edit the content:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$name in flexslider_add() (line
>   395 of
>   /data/home/buso01/domains/busoniu.net/public_html/projects/sites/all/modules/flexslider/flexslider.module).
>   Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$name in flexslider_add() (line
>   398 of
>   /data/home/buso01/domains/busoniu.net/public_html/projects/sites/all/modules/flexslider/flexslider.module).

In console chrome I can see this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a
>   functionflexslider.load.js?nk4e6d:41 (anonymous
>   function)jquery.js?v=1.4.4:34 b.extend.eachjquery.js?v=1.4.4:27
>   b.fn.b.eachjquery.once.js?v=1.2:55
>   $.fn.onceflexslider.load.js?nk4e6d:34
>   _flexslider_initflexslider.load.js?nk4e6d:24 Drupal.behaviors.flexslider.attachdrupal.js?nk4e6d:76 (anonymous
>   function)jquery.js?v=1.4.4:33 b.extend.eachdrupal.js?nk4e6d:74
>   Drupal.attachBehaviorsdrupal.js?nk4e6d:412 (anonymous
>   function)jquery.js?v=1.4.4:30 b.extend.readyjquery.js?v=1.4.4:38 u

Comment: What versions are you using? Which jQuery Update you installed? What jQuery version is required?

Comment: I have drupal 7 and flexSlider 2.4. I don't know other specifications because I'm only creating the web site, but the host is someone else. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the Flexslider library in sites/all/libraries.

Check Status page for error with flexslider (admin/reports/status).

Comment: I did copy the lib to that location and the status is: `FlexSlider - FlexSlider library installed. version 2.4 '

Comment: From what I see on your page the flexslider js gets not loaded 'sites/all/libraries/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js' missing in the html. Maybe try to use another theme to see if it is theme related.

Comment: On Bartik 7.34 happens the same. can this be blocked by my online server provider?

Comment: and clear your cache too.

Comment: Ohh, now works... so do u know if I could be able to use the other theme with FlixSlider, or how to fix this issue with that theme? thank for helping

Comment: Try enabling other theme again and clear cache afterwards, maybe it will work then too. If not maybe rise a issue at themes queue

Comment: FYI: Googling this error brought me here. I already had the necessary javascript libraries, as this answer suggests. However, I migrated an impartial feature configuration from one site to another. Keep in mind that my FS implementation includes a view, FS definition and image style definition. Migrating these as well addressed the problem.